# Calculate Hausdorff distance between two meshes

Tags: 3d, qt5, mesh, cgal, point-clouds

I am trying to find the deviation between two meshes. For e.g., the difference between two sets of points defined in 3d space, and I plan to visualize the distance using some 3d visualization tool for e.g., Qt3D or some OpenGL-based library.

I have two sets of meshes, basically two `.stl` files. I have programmed to read them as inputs. Now, I need to calculate the deviation between the corresponding meshes. For this, I understand that the Hausdorff distance is a possible mathematical tool. Is there any library which calculates the Hausdorff distance between two meshes?

I managed to find one piece of code, but it's more or less a program in itself. It's called [M.E.S.H.](http://mesh.berlios.de/). I don't want to use it as it is because:

1. it's written in C;
2. I want to develop my own application (using a library, of course).

The other questions point towards the mathematical algorithm, I don't plan to implement the algorithm on my own.

I am using Qt5 with MSVC2010 (32 bit).

Comment: So, do you want to compute the Hausdorff distance between the **meshes** or between two **point sets** sampled from the meshes?

Comment: I want to calculate the Hausdorff distance between two meshes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem so complex to implement: http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/publications/papers/metro.pdf

Answer (score 7):

You can use `igl::hausdorff` in [libigl](http://libigl.github.io). If your first mesh has vertices in the rows of a matrix `VA` with face indices `FA` and likewise `VB` and `FB` for your second mesh, then

```
double d;
igl::hausdorff(VA,FA,VB,FB,d);
```

will compute the Hausdorff distance `d` between the two meshes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it can help, but have a look at the dual quadric metric http://www.computingscience.nl/docs/vakken/ddm/slides/papers/garland2.pdf